# PHP: Listen to Syslog Messages

Tags: php, apache, udp, syslog, forward

I am using Windows.

I want an application to listen to UDP Port 514 (Syslog) and pass (forward) messages to a PHP file, so I can parse and save them to my database.

Is there any application, server or something (maybe apache mina, or any syslog apps) that can do this for me?

If there is a good solution in Linux, maybe I try to migrate my application from Windows to Linux. But it should be safe and promising.

Comment: http://socketo.me/ is a great php listener, Not sure about UDP but it should be able to do what you want. you set up the server loop and run the required code.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has no native concept of syslog ([RFC 3164](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt) and [RFC 5424](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt)), however, you can use a converter to read the windows event log and convert them to syslog using various tools such as [SNARE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snare/files/) and use a Virtual machine running a syslog tool such as [LogZilla](https://www.logzilla.net/download.html).

The entire process to set this up is quite easy.

1. Install Snare and change the default setting to use the syslog port (514) per the guide [here](http://demo.logzilla.net/help/receiving_data/receiving_windows_events).
2. Download the [LogZilla VM](https://logzilla.sh/LogZilla-NEO.ova)
3. Install the [VMWare Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0) (free)
4. Boot the VM up and read the login information on the screen